# Is it possible to embed a custom font on to your site/install it on your host?

Tags: javascript, fonts, styles, typography, custom-font

I've researched this a fair bit and the answer I've found is that there is only a limited number of web fonts available which seems a bit old fashioned to me. Would it not be possible to upload a custom font to your web host and use javascript (or something else, forgive my ignorance and noobishness) to read the custom font so when a visitor comes to your site it doesn't matter that they don't have your custom font installed it's just loaded off the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed custom fonts using CSS.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
  url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}


body {
  font-family: 'MyFontFamily', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

[source: css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

Comment: where do I get the .eot .woff and .svg versions of the font? when I download most custom font they just come with .ttf - *update* it seems that http://fontsquirrel.com/ will allow me to convert fonts to any format

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: cool_font;
    src: url('cool_font.ttf');
}
p.custom_font{
    font-family: cool_font; /* no .ttf */
}
```

From http://www.howtoplaza.com/how-to-use-custom-fonts-on-your-website-with-css

Comment: thanks, that's awesome! :D so I just upload whatever custom font on to my host, declare this at the top of my  css:                                                       @font-face {
    font-family: cool_font;
    src: url('cool_font.ttf');
}                                                                    and then afterwards I can use it on any element? sweet